# how to interrupt thread on Python

Tags: python, multithreading, interrupt, python-multithreading

Is it possible a intterrupt a python threading, example i want interrupt that thread 30 seconds later.

```
import threading
import time

def waiting():
    print("thread is started")
    time.sleep(60)
    print("thread is finished")

thread = threading.Thread(target=waiting, name="thread_1")
thread.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

I find the solution, i am using multiprocessing module, the solution example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def waiting():
    print("thread is started")
    time.sleep(60)
    print("thread is finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=waiting)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(30)
    p.terminate()
```

Process is started and terminate 30 seconds later.